# NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of - in Angular 14

Tags: angular

In my Angular 14 Ionic 6 app, I started getting this error:

```
NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-list' (used in the 'SelectContactComponent' component template).
If the 'ngIf' is an Angular control flow directive, please make sure that either the 'NgIf' directive or the 'CommonModule' is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
```

(I get it twice, for the two *ngIf directives I have - see below in the template).

This code used to work, and the only thing I can think of that may have caused this. was an Upgrade of Angular to 14, and Ionic to 6.

All other similar questions I found here point out to the need to import CommonModule, add it to the Imports and Declare the component - it is all in place (as it was working).

**Any idea what may have gone wrong?**

The module:
***add-helper.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AddHelperPage } from './add-helper.page';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SelectContactComponent } from './contacts/select-contact.component';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule,
    Ng2SearchPipeModule
  ],
  declarations: [AddHelperPage, SelectContactComponent],
  exports: [AddHelperPage, SelectContactComponent],
  providers: [SelectContactComponent]
})
export class AddHelperPageModule {}
```

The child component controller:
***select-contact.component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

import { Contacts } from '@capacitor-community/contacts';
import { IContact } from '../../../Utilities/contact.model'

import { Dialogs, DialogType } from '../../../Utilities/dialogs';
import { ModalController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-contact',
  templateUrl: './select-contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-contact.component.scss'],
})

export class SelectContactComponent implements OnInit {

  ...

  constructor(private dialogs: Dialogs, private modalCtrl: ModalController, private platform: Platform) { }

  ngOnInit() {
} 
...
...

}
```

The child component template:
***select-contact.component.html***

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button icon="chevron-back-outline"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Select Contact</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-searchbar placeholder="Search..." [(ngModel)]="filterTerm" animated="true"></ion-searchbar>
</ion-header>


  <ion-content [fullscreen]="true"  class="ion-padding">
    
    <ion-list *ngIf="!selectPhone">
      <ion-item *ngFor="let data of contacts | filter:filterTerm" button (click)="contactSelected(data)">
        <ion-label>{{data.displayName}}</ion-label>        
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-card *ngIf="selectPhone">  
      <ion-list>
        <ion-radio-group allow-empty-selection="false" name="radio-group" (ionChange)="phoneNumberSelected($event)" #radioGroup>
          <ion-list-header>
            <ion-label>Select {{selectedContactName}} best phone number</ion-label>
          </ion-list-header>
    
          <ion-item *ngFor="let item of phones">
            <ion-label>{{item.number}} ({{item.label}})</ion-label>
            <ion-radio slot="start" name="{{item.label}}" value="{{item.number}}"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
    
        </ion-radio-group>
      </ion-list>
    
      <!-- Phone selection form buttons -->
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center">
          <ion-col size="12" class="ion-text-center">
            <ion-buttons id="phone-select-buttons">
              
              <ion-button class="submit-btn phone-select-button" (click)="submitSelectedPhone()" fill="solid" [disabled]="(!selectedPhone)">Select</ion-button>
              <ion-button class="cancel-btn phone-select-button" type="next" (click)="cancelPhoneSelection()" fill="outline" color="medium">Cancel</ion-button>     
              
            </ion-buttons>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-card>

  </ion-content>
```

Do note that the child component does NOT have its own Module (i.e., no *select-contact.module.ts* file).

Btw, this child component is opened as a Modal by the parent (add-helper.page.ts) like this:

```
async pickContact() {
    this.selectContact = true;
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: SelectContactComponent,
      componentProps: { }
    });

    modal.onDidDismiss().then((contact) => {
      console.log('Received contact result from child: ', contact);
           
    });

    await modal.present();
    
  }
```

Comment: Try resetting the Angular Language Server, as well as Typescript Language Server from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) in VSCode

Comment: Thanks. I'm not using the Angular Language Server extension. Why would this has to do with VSCode, anyway? I could use notepad to write my code :)